# Add images and Text to my quiz application (C# Desktop)

Tags: c#, web-applications, desktop-application

I have Quiz web application which the admin can add a question; this can be text and images . The options can also be text and images as seen below.
I have been asked to reproduce this in a redistributable desktop application using c#.
I am finding it difficult to do this sine there is no single control in windows forms that can display both text and image.

I have attached some graphical illustrations below.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a control that contains an image and text, why not building a `UserControl` that takes both?

(If you are working with graphics, I would recommend WPF.)

Comment: How do i get started about that please. Can u give me guidelines . I would appreciate that pls

Comment: @OkwuPrecious There are many tutorials online, you should really take more effort in searching things online. Your question has been answered here already and it was easy to find by Google by using the term "C# WinForms UserControl Tutorial": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388333/how-to-use-usercontrol-in-window-forms-programming-c-sharp There is also an official article in the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx You should also search for UserControl examples to even understand  the structure of those a way better.